# Front end for CLIPS

Tags: user-interface, clips

I have just been introdcude to the CLIPS expert system. Does anyone know how difficult it is to integrate a GUI in Java or C++ for this tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some years ago I developed a CLIPS application using Java AWT graphics and it was not difficult at all.  It was a JFrame Application and painting in a Canvas class. I no longer have the code though.

But if I would started today. I would probably use [Processing](http://processing.org/)  to show the results. It is java based , easy to paint graphics and you can integrate any java code or library with it.

Answer (score 0):

There are four example programs here with that show how to integrate a java GUI with CLIPS: http://sourceforge.net/projects/clipsrules/files/CLIPS/6.30/CLIPSJNI_0.3.zip/download